# Modificador de acesso Internal X public

Tags: c#, .net

1. Quando utilizar public ou internal?
2. Existe algum vantagem/desvantagem entre eles?

Comment: As respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a dizer quais são as diferenças entre elas e não a responder ao que foi perguntado. A razão é que são as diferenças que ditarão a sua utilização e em face disso as suas vantagens/desvantagens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O modificador de acesso `public` faz com que seu método/propriedade (ou qualquer outra coisa) possa ser acessado de qualquer lugar da sua aplicação (ou de outras). Isso quer dizer que será possível acessar o elemento mesmo que ele seja uma função interna de uma biblioteca que seja importada via referência.

O modificador `internal` faz com que o elemento só possa ser acessado dentro daquele mesmo assembly, ou seja, o elemento só será acessado dentro do **.exe** ou **.dll** que foi criado.

> Quando utilizar public ou internal?

Isso só você pode decidir. Embora seja mais comum usar `internal` em elementos que não possam ser acessados/modificados por outro assembly (no caso de estar desenvolvendo uma **dll**).

> Existe algum vantagem/desvantagem entre eles?

Outra coisa que só o desenvolvedor da aplicação pode responder. O elemento pode ser acessado fora do assembly que foi criado? Se sim, use `public`, caso contrário, use `internal`.

Comment: Só faltou responder se `Existe algum vantagem/desvantagem entre eles`

Comment: Pronto @rubStackOverflow